# Configuring PHP Memcached sessions for clustering

Tags: php, apache, session, memcached

I already had a look to a few posts about this but can't get it to work

I have 2 ubuntu servers, for testing, I installed the following:

```
apt-get install memcached
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install php5
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get install php5-memcached
```

my /etc/memcached.conf has

Server 1

```
-m -p 11211 -l 192.168.0.1
```

Server 2

```
-m -p 11211 -l 192.168.0.2
```

my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Server 1

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "192.168.0.1:11211,192.168.0.2:11211"
```

Server 2

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "192.168.0.2:11211,192.168.0.1:11211"
```

and my small test on both /var/www/

```
session_start();

echo “Session save_handler is: “.ini_get(”session.save_handler”).”
“;
echo “Session save_path is: “.ini_get(”session.save_path”).”
“;

if(isset($_SESSION['KEY']))
{
echo “KEY found: “.$_SESSION['KEY'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['KEY'] = ‘test’;
echo ‘KEY set to: ‘.$_SESSION['KEY'];
}
```

It works for each individual server, meaning it does save the session. But i do not get the session "copy" in the opposite server (it starts a new session no matter what)

I really don't know if I have a whoopsie on the test code or if I'm missing a conf. I also tried memcache (withouth d) and adding tcp:// to the paths, but the result is the exact sth

Update:

To be more clear, I want my session to be saved on both servers, the problem is it only saves on their local memcqched, never on the remote one. According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php it should be working

Comment: This article may help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04 - it details the settings to allow memcached to replicate.

Comment: Note that it seems that the memcache extension, not the memcached extension will handle replication

Answer (score 0):

Memcached does not replicate data onto each server. You can increase memcache storage capacity by adding additional memcache servers, but it does not replicate.  If you want that functionality you should look into repcached.
http://repcached.lab.klab.org/.

Comment: Hmm i was under the impression, by many posts, that I was able to tell each server to save on both memcacjes at the sametime